# How is the probability prediction of a binary classifier predicted

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I have a trained BDT and with sklearn  [predict_proba(X)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.predict_proba), I can get a probability between 0 and 1 for a predicted feature. I am now wondering, how this probability is calculated?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y is beta0 + beta1*x1 + beta2*x2 .....+ epsilong`

`probability` = `((e power y)/(1 + e power y))`

This is the how it is been calculated.